# SPARQL query restric answer

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology

I have the following query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>         
PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>
SELECT ?r (count(distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?oi)  {
?r rec:Ingrediente ?Ingrediente. 
     filter not exists {
        ?r rec:Ingrediente ?other_ingredient 
        filter( ?other_ingredient not in ( rec:Aceite, rec:Cebolla ) )  
     }
   }
GROUP BY ?r 
order by (count(distinct ?Ingrediente))
```

And I get this:

```
 ?r         ?oi
 Recipe1    1
 Recipe2    2
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
 ?r         ?oi     ?PreparationMode        ?IngredientList
 Recipe1    1       First, you have to..    ing1, ing2, ing3... 
 Recipe2    2       First, you have to..    ing1, ing2, ing3...
```

I tried to do this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>         
PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>
SELECT ?r (count(distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?oi) ?mo  ?sa{
?r rec:Ingrediente ?Ingrediente. 
?m rdf:type rec:ModoPreparacion.
?m rdfs:label ?mo.
?s rdf:type rec:ListaIngredientes.
?s rdfs:label ?sa.
filter not exists {
  ?r rec:Ingrediente ?other_ingredient 
  filter( ?other_ingredient not in ( rec:Aceite, rec:Cebolla ) )    
   }
}
GROUP BY ?r ?mo ?sa
order by (count(distinct ?Ingrediente))
```

But I get the recipe name multiply lots of times and I dont know how to fix that. Any idea? Thanks!!!!

This is the DDBB structure:

[image]

Each recipe has ingredients and a preparation mode:

[image]

Each preparation mode has a label with a description:

[image]

And each ingredient list has a label with other description:
[image]

And also here is the protégé ddbb:

http://webprotege.stanford.edu/#Edit:projectId=bb11a09e-29f5-47c5-b2f9-a81c3a88aa9d[5](http://webprotege.stanford.edu/#Edit:projectId=bb11a09e-29f5-47c5-b2f9-a81c3a88aa9d)

Comment: You've posted a number of questions now, many of which would be pretty simple to answer if you'd post a sample of your data.  In comments, you've been asked numerous times to provide samples of the data.  Please note that "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"  If you don't provide sample data on which to run your queries, the problem is not really easily reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no connection between the variables ?r and ?m:

```
?r rec:Ingrediente ?Ingrediente. 
?m rdf:type rec:ModoPreparacion.
```

This says "find (a recipe) ?r with an ingredient ?Ingrediente and an ?m with type rec:ModoPreparacion."  That means that you find every possible combination.  Compare with data like:

```
:John a :Person; :hasAge 30 .
:Bill a :Person; :hasAge 35 .
```

If you write a query like

```
select ?person ?age {
  ?person a :Person .
  ?y :hasAge ?age .
}
```

You'll get four rows in your results:

```
John 30
Bill 30
John 35
Bill 35
```